# Dynamic Bracket ' } ' Image in table column

Tags: php, html, css

I am creating on table with list of data using PHP,based on one array as follow

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  int(7)
  [8]=>
  int(3)
  [11]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Using this array,I am implementing  and  tag. As per following screenshot

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2lGXvfrHLQAaEh5UXFQZUFmYW8/view?usp=sharing

```
<table width="70%">
    <?php $isheader = false;
    foreach ($pmatrix as $z):?>
        <?php if (array_key_exists($z[1], $maker2)) {
            $isheader = true; ?>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }
        if ($isheader) { ?>
            <tr style="border-bottom: solid 1px grey;">
                <?php foreach ($z[2] as $paramName => $value) { ?>
                    <td><b><?php echo toCustomHeader($paramName) ?></b></td>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        <?php }
        $isheader = false; ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($z[2] as $paramName => $value) { ?>
                <td><?php echo $paramName == 'SiteName' ? toSubstanceTitle($value) : $value; ?>
                </td>
            <?php }
            if (array_key_exists($z[1], $maker2)) {
                $fsize = $maker2[$z[1]];
                $fsize = 25 * $fsize;
                $fwidth = 40;
                $fwidth = $fwidth . 'px';
                $fsize = $fsize . 'px';
                ?>
                <td rowspan=" <?php echo $maker2[$z[1]] ?>">
                    <img src="img/bracket.png"
                         style=" height: <?php echo $fsize; ?>;width: <?php echo $fwidth; ?>">
                </td>
                <td rowspan=" <?php echo $maker2[$z[1]] ?>"><b><?php echo toFormatSiteType($z[0]) ?></b>
                </td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <?php
    endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

please suggest me the proper size that I should apply for make this image , based on parent column. any one can just take dummy data and post example

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2lGXvfrHLQAaEh5UXFQZUFmYW8/view?usp=sharing true link

Comment: Can you upload the screenshot to another service such as imgur.com.

Comment: @C0dekid sure please check http://imgur.com/a/Iubo4